# HD recording via logitech c930e webcam

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg, gstreamer, cheese

I want to record an Hd video stream via this webcam (hopefully using a script)
to capture simultaneously with a screen recording into one container. (you can see the pipeline code I've used before, below)

as far as I know v4l2 doesn't support 1080 recording for this type of camera in fps more than 5 and I really need a hd stream with at least 20 fps. is there any other way or application for this purpose?

below is the pipeline code of **gstreamer** and it's based on v4l2 and it can capture only 720P in 10 fps which is not enough at all! I do believe that ffmpeg has the same result since it's using v4l2 too. (please note that it's possible to capture 1080 with 5 fps (the command below) but I guess you can imagine how the quality would be(!) therefore I need fps more than 20)

I really appreciate if you could help me with this!

here is the gstreamers' pipeline code:

```
 gst-launch -e mpegtsmux name="muxer" ! filesink location=/home/sina/Desktop/UI4.ts \
 v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280 ,height=720, \
  framerate=10/1 ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! muxer. v4l2src \
  device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1024 ,height=768,framerate=10/1 \
 ! x264enc !  muxer.  pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo"\
  ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc target=1 cbr=true  ! muxer.
```

FYI here is the outcome of **v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats**:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
 Index       : 0
 Type        : Video Capture
 Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
 Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
     Size: Discrete 640x480
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 160x120
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 176x144
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 320x180
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 320x240
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 352x288
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 424x240
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 480x270
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 640x360
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 800x448
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 800x600
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 848x480
         Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 960x540
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 1024x576
         Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 1280x720
         Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 1600x896
         Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 1920x1080
         Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 2304x1296
         Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
     Size: Discrete 2304x1536
         Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)

 Index       : 1
 Type        : Video Capture
 Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
 Name        : MJPEG
     Size: Discrete 640x480
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 160x120
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 176x144
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 320x180
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 320x240
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 352x288
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 424x240
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 480x270
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 640x360
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 800x448
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 800x600
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 848x480
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 960x540
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 1024x576
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 1280x720
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 1600x896
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
Size: Discrete 1920x1080
    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture with FullHD video with more than 5fps you need the camera to use an encoded format and not raw video. From the v4l2 list-formats output you can see that it supports 30fps in FullHD with MJPEG.

So instead of using video/x-raw-yuv for your caps you should use image/jpeg. Mind you that if you need the final result to be H264 use a decoder before reencoding (jpegdec).

With that said, you are using gstreamer 0.10 that is now 3 years obsolete and unmantained. It is strongly recommended to move to 1.x version that is the current upstream version and has, among others, improved support for non-raw cameras.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it really helped me!
I made another question about how to run two pipeline in sync simultaneously to record one from webcam and another one from frame grabber,
can you please take a look at that question as well? I really appreciate your help!